# UIAutomation and NSNotification

Tags: ios, asynchronous, ios-ui-automation

I want to be able to use UIAutomation to test an app.  The problem I'm running into is, I need to download allot of data from the network.  Is there a way to pause a UIAutomation script until a NSNotification is posted, or do I just need to `delay()` longer than I think is necessary to download the data.  Waiting a set amount of time isn't preferable because sometimes data doesn't need to be re-downlaoded.

Any help / links is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jack's answer works for most details, but some of the network work happens on a background queue, and there isn't a progress indicator.

I ended up writing a helper that sticks a `CGRectZero` UIView into an element.  We can then wait until this element becomes valid.  It's not as clean as I would like it to be but it's woking.

```
waitForElementNamed: function(name, element, timeout) {
  timeout = timeout || 10
  log("Waiting for " + timeout + " seconds")
  var valid = false
  for (var i = 0; i < timeout; i++) {
      UIATarget.localTarget().pushTimeout(.5)
      valid = element.elements()[name].isValid()
      if (valid) {
      log("Found Element " + name)
      return
      }
      UIATarget.localTarget().popTimeout()
      target.delay(.5)
  }
  if (!valid) {
      failed("Wait Timedout [" + timeout + "]")
  }
}
```

It's not pretty but it works.

Answer (score 2):

UIAutomation has a nifty function called `waitForInvalid()`. If you've got a progress bar or something that will get displayed and then removed after the data is done downloading, you could use that.

This also works for a case in which the user already has the data and you don't show the UI, since the function would immediately return.